# Получение панорамы улицы, а не объекта

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Столкнулся с проблемой, когда создается плеер с панорамой

```
      this.panorama = ymaps.panorama.createPlayer(
        'yandex-map',
        [this.placeMarkCoord?.latitude, this.placeMarkCoord?.longitude],
        {
          layer: "yandex#panorama"
        }
      )
```

Указываю layer: yandex#panorama, но, если существует панорама "внутри объекта" (если координаты указывают на какое-либо здание), подгружается именно она, что мне не требуется.
Если перебирать существующие панорамы методом *locate*, то отображается только панорама "в здании", хотя рядом есть улицы с панорамами.

Пример координаты с таким поведением: 37.59132093, 55.7068543599963

В документации Яндекса не нашел решений.

Comment: Ох, лучше так же продублируйте вопрос на англ версию SOF

Answer (score 0):

Текущий метод добавления панорамы [locate()](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/panorama.locate.html) в API Яндекс.Карт не предполагает возможности выбора одной из ближайших панорам или панораму определённого типа.

Добавляется панорама самая близкая к заданным вами координатам. Если вам для вашего проекта нужна конкретная панорама, найдите её на карте и пропишите в вызове найденные координаты. Случайная панорама со случайным направлением взгляда едва ли будет нужна реальным пользователям при работе с вашим продуктом.